# ReactNative Cannot uncheck checkbox

Tags: react-native, expo

I have the most basic usage of a checkbox.

```
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  return (
         <View style={{ marginTop: 64 }}>
             <CheckBox checked={checked} onValueChange={setChecked} />
         </View>)
}
```

My issue is that once I check the box, it becomes impossible to uncheck it.

I have the same issue if I just use this without any props:

```
<CheckBox/>
```

Comment: Where do you import `CheckBox` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox, you need value prop to the checkbox.
Eg. `<CheckBox value={checked} onValueChange={setChecked} />`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the way you check the `CheckBox`

```
//                             added the correct setChecked 
<CheckBox value={checked} onValueChange={() => setChecked(prev => !prev)} />
```